# Get stream from FLV (PHP, CURL)

Tags: stream, flv, flowplayer

I try to do something like this. I want to stream FLV or MP4 file into my player on the site (i use flowplayer).I get link to video by CURL, and set in flowplayer "clip" to that url. But, i have one problem. I can't rewind to forward when it's not loaded.

Is possible to start from half of video if i stream file from outside my host ??

Answer (score 0):

It depends whether the remote videos contain the appropriate metadata.

To start playback from the middle of the video, the player must first load the start of the video, parse the `onMetadata` event, and parse an array containing the mapping of keyframe times to byte positions.

When dumped in the flvmeta tool, the metadata may look like this:

```
{
    'hasMetadata' => true
    'hasVideo' => true
    'hasAudio' => true
    'duration' => 76.826
    'lasttimestamp' => 76.8
    'lastkeyframetimestamp' => 74.449
    'width' => 608
    'height' => 336
    'videodatarate' => 472.876919109
    'framerate' => 23.3124202744
    'audiodatarate' => 31.25
    'audiosamplerate' => 22000
    'audiosamplesize' => 16
    'stereo' => false
    'filesize' => 5036611
    'videosize' => 4671635
    'audiosize' => 342596
    'datasize' => 5017666
    'metadatacreator' => 'flvmeta 1.1-dev'
    'metadatadate' => Wed, 23 Dec 2009 17:37:20 Paris, Madrid
    'audiocodecid' => 2
    'videocodecid' => 2
    'audiodelay' => 0
    'canSeekToEnd' => false
    'hasCuePoints' => false
    'cuePoints' => [
    ]
    'hasKeyframes' => true
    'keyframes' => {
        'times': [
            0
            0.5
            0.709
            1.21
            1.71
            2.211
            2.711
            3.212
            3.712
        ]
        'filepositions': [
            3534
            30982
            47899
            71050
            96847
            123067
            161269
            194445
            225145
        ]
    }
}
```

This allows the player to know the total duration for the file, and seek to the nearest keyframe from the wanted time in the video seeker control using a partial HTTP request instead of waiting for the file to load until the desired point.

There are some tools to inject these metadata, like flvtool2, yamdi, and my own flvmeta.
That will work if you can modify the remote files, or if they already contain those metadata.